# How to merge videos and add audio in a single command using ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I use the following commands to concat audio-less video files to one and add audio to it,

To concat individual videos,

`ffmpeg  -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4 -i 5.mp4 -filter_complex 'concat=n=5:v=1:a=0[out]'  -map '[out]' -strict -2 -y video_withoutaudio.mp4`

To add audio,

`ffmpeg -i video_withoutaudio.mp4 -i audio.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict -2 video_withaudio.mp4`

is there a way to combine these two commands to one?

My requirement is to optimise the commands as I have 1000+ commands taking a lot of time to complete, hoping combining these two to one will save some time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg  -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4 -i 5.mp4 -i audio.mp4 
        -filter_complex 'concat=n=5:v=1:a=0[out]'
        -map '[out]' -map a -c:a aac -strict -2 -y video_withaudio.mp4
```

I assume that none of the concat videos have audio. If they do, the result will be unexpected.

Comment: Yes, none of the videos have audio.
When I try to execute the following command, I get "Stream map 'a' matches no streams." error.

Comment: Modified your the above command to following and it worked,
ffmpeg  -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4 -i 5.mp4 -i audio.mp4 
        -filter_complex 'concat=n=5:v=1:a=0[out]'
        -map '[out]' -map 5 -c:a aac -strict -2 -y video_withaudio.mp4

Comment: I just tried this solution and its not working.  -filter_complex complaines about having an unconnected output.  kind of follows at the audio is not mentioned.  May have this wored with older versions?

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report.